# db4o SODA compare field values

Tags: c#, db4o, soda

```
class SomeClass
{
  private DateTime fieldA;
  private DateTime fieldB;
}
```

Using SODA, what is the proper way to select all objects whose fieldA is greater than fieldB?

Something like this?

```
var query = this.ObjectContainer.Query();
query.Constrain(typeof(SomeClass));
query.Descend("fieldA").Constrain(query.Descend("fieldB")).Greater();
var list = query.Execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean how to express a query like the following (SQL)

```
select * from SomeTable where fieldA > fieldB
```

in SODA, right?

I am afraid this is not possible (at least not without using an evaluation or a native query - which, in this case, will run as an evaluation anyway).

Best